# TSQL remove "commands executed successfully" like messages(logs)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm making a set of dynamic queries and use 'print' to make the queries so that we can run in another environment

The problem i'm facing is "started executing query" and "command completed successfully" like comments with my output. So its getting difficult to extract the actual queries

Any way to suppress this? Sample is attached[image]

Comment: You could select the statements instead of printing them?

Comment: @DaleK I tried to do that. But it will be different datasets. I'm trying a work around similar. Keep a query temp table and instead of printing there insert to that

But i was looking some thing like 

"SET NOCOUNT ON"(It stops logging x rows effected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to debug something or generate data, you can create additional table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo._TEST
(
   [RowID] INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
  ,[value] NVARCHAR(MAX)
);
```

in your code instead:

```
PRINT @Query;
```

do

```
INSERT INTO dbo._TEST ([value])
SELECT @Query;
```

Then, it will be more easier for you to get the records or manipulated them (for example building a statement for execution with code).

Also, you can just type `SELECT @Query` instead `PRINT @Query` but it won't be so useful when selecting all data.

Comment: Thank you..

I started in the same way(After posting the query got the logic)

But I was looking some thing simple, very much simple like 

"SET NOCOUNT ON"

Comment: @BineshNambiarC Currently, there is no option in the SSMS to suppress this message.